# Modifiying global variables with multiprocessing

Tags: python, global-variables, multiprocessing

I want to modify a list by appending to it items generated by some functions that work in parallel. Something like this:

```
import multiprocessing
my_list=[]

def f(x):
    global my_list
    my_list.append(x)

for i in range(6):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(i,))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()

for job in jobs:
    job.join()
```

I expect to see something like:

```
In : my_list
Out: [0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

However the output is an empty list:

```
In : my_list
Out: []
```

Do you know why this is happening and how can I adapt the code to make it modify the global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the data structures defined in the multiprocessing module rather than standard lists: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: Looks like multiprocessing.Manager is solving my problem. Thanks!